# Load and transform json with Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load, parse and transform json messages I get from debezium but can't understand how this is working.
Messages are received from Kafka, but for now, I put 2 of these messages into a json file I'm loading from local.

This content file is

```
{"schema": {"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "NOM_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "DES_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "COD_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "OBS_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_FILMADO"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_ACTIVO"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "COD_LINEA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_HORARIA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_DIARIA5"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_DIARIA15"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_DIARIA20"},{"type": "int16","optional": true,"field": "DURACION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_BLOQUE"},{"type": "int16","optional": true,"field": "FG_POSICION"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "ABREVIATURA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "FEC_ALTA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "FEC_MODIF"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "USUARIO"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "FUNCION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_PROGRAMA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_AVANCE"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_ACTIVO_PASIVO"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_PAQUETE"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_AVANCE_MULT"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "VERSION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_ARCHIVO_DIGITAL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_PROD_PLACEMENT"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_SATURACION_BLOQUE"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_SATURACION_TIPOL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_IIEE_12_MINUTOS"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "FG_INFORMATIVOS"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "EMAILS_NOTIF"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPOL_LINEAL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_HBBTV"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_HBBTV_INT"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "COLOR"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "ORDEN_COLOR"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPOLOGIA_TO_IIEE"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_CREATIVIDAD"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_NEGO2"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "FG_SATURACION_DOBLE"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "COD_CLASIF"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_BLOQUE_ADR"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPO_PUBLI_REEMPLAZABLE"}],"optional": true,"name": "topic.BBDD.TABLA.Value","field": "before"},{"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "NOM_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "DES_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "COD_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "OBS_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_FILMADO"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_ACTIVO"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "COD_LINEA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_HORARIA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_DIARIA5"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_DIARIA15"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_DIARIA20"},{"type": "int16","optional": true,"field": "DURACION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_BLOQUE"},{"type": "int16","optional": true,"field": "FG_POSICION"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "ABREVIATURA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "FEC_ALTA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "FEC_MODIF"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "USUARIO"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "FUNCION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_PROGRAMA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_AVANCE"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_ACTIVO_PASIVO"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_PAQUETE"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_AVANCE_MULT"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "VERSION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_ARCHIVO_DIGITAL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_PROD_PLACEMENT"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_SATURACION_BLOQUE"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_SATURACION_TIPOL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_IIEE_12_MINUTOS"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "FG_INFORMATIVOS"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "EMAILS_NOTIF"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPOL_LINEAL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_HBBTV"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_HBBTV_INT"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "COLOR"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "ORDEN_COLOR"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPOLOGIA_TO_IIEE"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_CREATIVIDAD"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_NEGO2"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "FG_SATURACION_DOBLE"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "COD_CLASIF"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_BLOQUE_ADR"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPO_PUBLI_REEMPLAZABLE"}],"optional": true,"name": "topic.BBDD.TABLA.Value","field": "after"},{"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "version"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "connector"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "name"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "ts_ms"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"name": "io.debezium.data.Enum","version": 1,"parameters": {"allowed": "true,last,false,incremental"},"default": "false","field": "snapshot"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "db"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "sequence"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "schema"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "table"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "txId"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "scn"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "commit_scn"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "lcr_position"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "rs_id"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "ssn"},{"type": "int32","optional": true,"field": "redo_thread"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "user_name"}],"optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.Source","field": "source"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "op"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "ts_ms"},{"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "id"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "total_order"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "data_collection_order"}],"optional": true,"name": "event.block","version": 1,"field": "transaction"}],"optional": false,"name": "topic.BBDD.TABLA.Envelope","version": 1},"payload": {"before": null,"after": {"NOM_TIPOLOGIA": "PRUEBA TEST","DES_TIPOLOGIA": "PRUEBA TEST","COD_TIPOLOGIA": 4851,"OBS_TIPOLOGIA": null,"FG_FILMADO": 0,"FG_ACTIVO": 1,"COD_LINEA": 1,"FG_HORARIA": 0,"FG_DIARIA5": 0,"FG_DIARIA15": 0,"FG_DIARIA20": 0,"DURACION": 20,"FG_BLOQUE": 0,"FG_POSICION": null,"ABREVIATURA": "MITEST","FEC_ALTA": 1700484244000,"FEC_MODIF": 1700484244000,"USUARIO": "JMLD","FUNCION": "ALTA","FG_PROGRAMA": 0,"FG_AVANCE": 0,"FG_ACTIVO_PASIVO": null,"FG_PAQUETE": null,"FG_AVANCE_MULT": 0,"VERSION": 0,"FG_ARCHIVO_DIGITAL": 0,"FG_PROD_PLACEMENT": 0,"FG_SATURACION_BLOQUE": 0,"FG_SATURACION_TIPOL": 0,"FG_IIEE_12_MINUTOS": 0,"FG_INFORMATIVOS": 0,"EMAILS_NOTIF": null,"COD_TIPOL_LINEAL": null,"FG_HBBTV": 0,"FG_HBBTV_INT": 0,"COLOR": "c0c0c0","ORDEN_COLOR": null,"COD_TIPOLOGIA_TO_IIEE": null,"COD_CREATIVIDAD": 13,"COD_NEGO2": 4,"FG_SATURACION_DOBLE": 0,"COD_CLASIF": 1,"FG_BLOQUE_ADR": 0,"COD_TIPO_PUBLI_REEMPLAZABLE": null},"source": {"version": "2.3.4.Final","connector": "oracle","name": "topic","ts_ms": 1700480644000,"snapshot": "false","db": "PARGOS","sequence": null,"schema": "BBDD","table": "TABLA","txId": "06001600e8070900","scn": "41366992495","commit_scn": "41366992516","lcr_position": null,"rs_id": "0x0010d3.0003c76e.01d8","ssn": 0,"redo_thread": 1,"user_name": "TEST_DEBEZIUM"},"op": "c","ts_ms": 1700480651495,"transaction": null}}
{"schema": {"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "NOM_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "DES_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "COD_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "OBS_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_FILMADO"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_ACTIVO"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "COD_LINEA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_HORARIA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_DIARIA5"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_DIARIA15"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_DIARIA20"},{"type": "int16","optional": true,"field": "DURACION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_BLOQUE"},{"type": "int16","optional": true,"field": "FG_POSICION"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "ABREVIATURA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "FEC_ALTA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "FEC_MODIF"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "USUARIO"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "FUNCION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_PROGRAMA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_AVANCE"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_ACTIVO_PASIVO"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_PAQUETE"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_AVANCE_MULT"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "VERSION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_ARCHIVO_DIGITAL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_PROD_PLACEMENT"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_SATURACION_BLOQUE"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_SATURACION_TIPOL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_IIEE_12_MINUTOS"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "FG_INFORMATIVOS"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "EMAILS_NOTIF"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPOL_LINEAL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_HBBTV"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_HBBTV_INT"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "COLOR"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "ORDEN_COLOR"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPOLOGIA_TO_IIEE"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_CREATIVIDAD"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_NEGO2"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "FG_SATURACION_DOBLE"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "COD_CLASIF"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_BLOQUE_ADR"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPO_PUBLI_REEMPLAZABLE"}],"optional": true,"name": "topic.BBDD.TABLA.Value","field": "before"},{"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "NOM_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "DES_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "COD_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "OBS_TIPOLOGIA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_FILMADO"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_ACTIVO"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "COD_LINEA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_HORARIA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_DIARIA5"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_DIARIA15"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_DIARIA20"},{"type": "int16","optional": true,"field": "DURACION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_BLOQUE"},{"type": "int16","optional": true,"field": "FG_POSICION"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "ABREVIATURA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "FEC_ALTA"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "FEC_MODIF"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "USUARIO"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "FUNCION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "FG_PROGRAMA"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_AVANCE"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_ACTIVO_PASIVO"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_PAQUETE"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_AVANCE_MULT"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "VERSION"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_ARCHIVO_DIGITAL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_PROD_PLACEMENT"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "FG_SATURACION_BLOQUE"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_SATURACION_TIPOL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_IIEE_12_MINUTOS"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "FG_INFORMATIVOS"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "EMAILS_NOTIF"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPOL_LINEAL"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_HBBTV"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_HBBTV_INT"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "COLOR"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"field": "ORDEN_COLOR"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPOLOGIA_TO_IIEE"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_CREATIVIDAD"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_NEGO2"},{"type": "int8","optional": true,"default": 0,"field": "FG_SATURACION_DOBLE"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"field": "COD_CLASIF"},{"type": "int8","optional": false,"default": 0,"field": "FG_BLOQUE_ADR"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "COD_TIPO_PUBLI_REEMPLAZABLE"}],"optional": true,"name": "topic.BBDD.TABLA.Value","field": "after"},{"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "version"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "connector"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "name"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "ts_ms"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"name": "io.debezium.data.Enum","version": 1,"parameters": {"allowed": "true,last,false,incremental"},"default": "false","field": "snapshot"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "db"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "sequence"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "schema"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "table"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "txId"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "scn"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "commit_scn"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "lcr_position"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "rs_id"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "ssn"},{"type": "int32","optional": true,"field": "redo_thread"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "user_name"}],"optional": false,"name": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.Source","field": "source"},{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "op"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"field": "ts_ms"},{"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "id"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "total_order"},{"type": "int64","optional": false,"field": "data_collection_order"}],"optional": true,"name": "event.block","version": 1,"field": "transaction"}],"optional": false,"name": "topic.BBDD.TABLA.Envelope","version": 1},"payload": {"before": {"NOM_TIPOLOGIA": "PRUEBA TEST UPDA","DES_TIPOLOGIA": "PRUEBA TEST","COD_TIPOLOGIA": 4851,"OBS_TIPOLOGIA": null,"FG_FILMADO": 0,"FG_ACTIVO": 1,"COD_LINEA": 1,"FG_HORARIA": 0,"FG_DIARIA5": 0,"FG_DIARIA15": 0,"FG_DIARIA20": 0,"DURACION": 30,"FG_BLOQUE": 0,"FG_POSICION": null,"ABREVIATURA": "MITEST","FEC_ALTA": 1700484244000,"FEC_MODIF": 1700484278000,"USUARIO": "JMLD","FUNCION": "MODIFICACION","FG_PROGRAMA": 0,"FG_AVANCE": 0,"FG_ACTIVO_PASIVO": null,"FG_PAQUETE": null,"FG_AVANCE_MULT": 0,"VERSION": 1,"FG_ARCHIVO_DIGITAL": 0,"FG_PROD_PLACEMENT": 0,"FG_SATURACION_BLOQUE": 0,"FG_SATURACION_TIPOL": 0,"FG_IIEE_12_MINUTOS": 0,"FG_INFORMATIVOS": 0,"EMAILS_NOTIF": null,"COD_TIPOL_LINEAL": null,"FG_HBBTV": 0,"FG_HBBTV_INT": 0,"COLOR": "c0c0c0","ORDEN_COLOR": null,"COD_TIPOLOGIA_TO_IIEE": null,"COD_CREATIVIDAD": 13,"COD_NEGO2": 4,"FG_SATURACION_DOBLE": 0,"COD_CLASIF": 1,"FG_BLOQUE_ADR": 0,"COD_TIPO_PUBLI_REEMPLAZABLE": null},"after": null,"source": {"version": "2.3.4.Final","connector": "oracle","name": "topic","ts_ms": 1700480703000,"snapshot": "false","db": "PARGOS","sequence": null,"schema": "BBDD","table": "TABLA","txId": "08001d00dca20900","scn": "41366992713","commit_scn": "41366992783","lcr_position": null,"rs_id": "0x0010d3.0003c7e6.0010","ssn": 0,"redo_thread": 1,"user_name": "TEST_DEBEZIUM"},"op": "d","ts_ms": 1700480724965,"transaction": null}}
```

So for each message, we have the schema to apply to the payload to load it.
My problem.. how to do that ?

Ignoring the schema could be :

```
val jsonDF = spark.read.json("createdelete.json")
val payloadBefore=jsonDF.select("payload.source.schema","payload.source.table","payload.op","payload.before.*","payload.source.commit_scn")
val payloadAfter=jsonDF.select("payload.source.schema","payload.source.table","payload.op","payload.after.*","payload.source.commit_scn")
val payload=payloadBefore.union(payloadAfter)
payload.createOrReplaceTempView("payload")

val query="""SELECT
p.* from payload p 
JOIN (SELECT
cod_tipologia,
max(commit_scn) as commit_scn
FROM payload 
GROUP BY cod_tipologia) j
on (p.cod_tipologia=j.cod_tipologia and p.commit_scn=j.commit_scn)
"""
val df=spark.sql(query)
....
```

But I can't figure out how to extract and apply the provided schema.

I tried to change my code with

```
val jsonDF = spark.read.json("createdelete.json")
val schema=spark.read.json("createdelete.json").select("schema").collect()(0).schema
val jsonDFE=spark.read.schema(schema).json("createdelete.json")
```

But now jsonDFE only contains a "schema" column, while I'm more interested by the payload one

I don't want to use anything specific to this json message (case class avoided) as each message can have a specific schema, and I'm trying to avoid creating more than 100 different case classes to handle them.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to select column named "schema", and then get the schema from that.  If you want the schema for the json file, just use `spark.read.json("yourfile").schema`

Comment: Hi, I saw that after posting my question. Nevertheless, your solution is not totally ok for my case. Doing that, the given schema will be the inferred schema. If payload.before is null in all the json messages (because of a massive insertion), there's no inferred schema for that column. Of if numeric values are small enough to infer an int instead of a long, or...  So my question is, how can I get the schema from the message, and then use to create my df?

Comment: No, apache spark from Cloudera. Is that important?

Comment: In that case you need to define your schema, not derive it.